# Custom android button with image

Tags: android, button, togglebutton

i have a problem with toggle button. I am trying to extend ButtonRectangle from library [navasmdc](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary) and i want to add image. Something like ImageButton with that ripple effect.

I have tried to set background drawable, but it doesn't have effect i want.

I tried to do my own toggle button, but it is over my skills with that ripple effect.

So i am asking.

1. Is it possible to extend layout and add ImageView?
2. If so, how is it done?

Here is my code, I have so far:

```
public class StyleableToggleButton extends ButtonRectangle implements StyleableView, Checkable {



private boolean checked = false;
private int primaryColor = Config.DEFAULT_PRIMARY_COLOR;
private int secondaryColor = Config.DEFAULT_SECONDARY_COLOR;
private float rippleSpeed = 18f;


public StyleableToggleButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    applyStyle();
    setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            toggle();
            applyStyle();
        }
    });
    setRippleSpeed(rippleSpeed);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.direction_in_w));
    }
}

@Override
public void setChecked(boolean b) {
    checked = b;
    applyStyle();
}

@Override
public boolean isChecked() {
    return checked;
}

@Override
public void toggle() {
    checked = !checked;
    applyStyle();
}

@Override
public void applyStyle() {

    if (checked){
        this.setBackgroundColor(primaryColor);
    }else {
        this.setBackgroundColor(secondaryColor);
    }
}

@Override
protected int makePressColor(){
    return !checked ? primaryColor : secondaryColor;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out answer later. I am still not sure about question 1., but you can extend it programmaticaly.

Answer to 2. question is addView(View v)

so my code looks like this:

```
public class StyleableToggleButton extends ButtonRectangle implements    StyleableView, Checkable {



private boolean checked = false;
private int primaryColor = Config.DEFAULT_PRIMARY_COLOR;
private int secondaryColor = Config.DEFAULT_SECONDARY_COLOR;
private float rippleSpeed = 18f;
private TextView textView;
private ImageView imageView;
private LinearLayout linearLayout;

private int minHeight;
private float fontSize = 16f;


public StyleableToggleButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    minHeight = (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels - AttUtils.dpToPx(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.height_att_activity_bar),getResources())) / 4;

    setupButton(); 

    setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            toggle();
            applyStyle();
        }
    });
    setRippleSpeed(rippleSpeed);


}


//This is where we add textView and imageView to existing layout. We just kept previous empty.
private void setupButton() {

    setMinimumHeight(minHeight);

    linearLayout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);


    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;
    layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;

    textView = new TextView(getContext());
    textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        textView.setTextAlignment(TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
    }
    textView.setTextSize(fontSize);

    layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;

    imageView = new ImageView(getContext());
    imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    linearLayout.addView(imageView);
    linearLayout.addView(textView);
    addView(linearLayout);
}

@Override
public void setChecked(boolean b) {
    checked = b;
    applyStyle();
}

@Override
public boolean isChecked() {
    return checked;
}

@Override
public void toggle() {
    checked = !checked;
    applyStyle();
}

@Override
public void applyStyle() {

    Drawable dr = imageView.getDrawable();
    if (checked){
        this.setBackgroundColor(primaryColor);
        textView.setTextColor(secondaryColor);
        if (dr != null) {
            dr.setColorFilter(secondaryColor, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
            imageView.setImageDrawable(dr);
        }
    }else {
        this.setBackgroundColor(secondaryColor);
        textView.setTextColor(primaryColor);
        if (dr != null) {
            dr.setColorFilter(primaryColor, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
            imageView.setImageDrawable(dr);
        }
    }

}

@Override
protected int makePressColor(){
    return !checked ? primaryColor : secondaryColor;
}


@Override
public void setText(String text){
    textView.setText(text);
}

public void setImage(Drawable drawable){
    imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
}

public void setLayoutMargin(int marginWidth, int marginHeight){
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.setMargins(marginWidth, marginHeight, marginWidth, marginHeight);
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}

public void setTextViewMargin(int marginWidth, int marginHeight){
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.setMargins(marginWidth, marginHeight, marginWidth, marginHeight);
    textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}

public void setImageViewMargin(int marginWidth, int marginHeight){
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.setMargins(marginWidth, marginHeight, marginWidth, marginHeight);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
```

}